# Error displayed in the console that doesn't stop the program

Tags: javascript, error-handling

If I run this code in `myScript.js`

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'badUrl', false); 
req.send(null);
```

I get the following in the console :

[image]

I am getting a red message in the console but no error was thrown and the execution of `myScript.js` isn't interupted.

What has happened technically to get the red display since no error was thrown ?

Comment: it did stop a part of the program

Comment: You'll get console warnings for 404 *HTTP* errors even when they don't stop anything in the js program